Finding reflexive, transitive closure
I got a relation like: R: A -> A -> bool.
Using this, I need to find an Rclose: A -> A -> bool such that Rclose
is the reflexive, transitive closure of R.
Am trying to do this in Coq in such a way that the resultant Rclose
won't have any Prop component and would be computation-friendly.
Along with a proof of correctness saying that Rclose really is the
refl-trans closure of R.
I was told that this would be a non-trivial thing to do.
Any thoughts on directions in which I can explore?
I can reformulate R to another type if needed if the meaning can be preserved.

How can one go about stating the theorem?
Would this be enough?
Inductive path (R: A -> A -> bool): Prop :=
| Self: forall a:A, path R a a
| Step: forall a b c:A,
    path R a b -> path R b c -> path R a c.
    
Theorem foo (A: Type): forall x y:A,
  Rclose x y <-> path R x y.


Edit:
I can assume that A is a finite type.
In fact, I had been thinking of making a type like this:
Inductive typ: Type :=
| One: typ
| Add: typ -> typ -> typ.

Fixpoint denote (t: typ): Type :=
  match t with
  | One => unit
  | Add a b => (denote a)+(denote b)%type
  end.

and having A like forall t:typ, denote t.
As in, forall {t: typ}, R: denote t -> denote t -> bool
Does that make finding closure possible?

As noted in Meven's answer this isn't possible in general. Do you have an assumption on A, such as that A is finite, that would make this possible?

@NaïmFavier Yeah, I can assume that A is finite. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. I have made an edit to my question.

In that case, finding the closure of R amounts to writing a (verified) algorithm for finding paths in finite undirected simple graphs.

@NaïmFavier How does one go about doing that? And by R x y, I meant a one-way link. Then I should be looking at a directed graph, right?

Why do you care about extraction? Are you fine with a very naïve algorithm, with terrible efficiency? In any case, you will need quite a bit of non-trivial machinery around finite sets, finite existentials… One good reference point might be MathComp's version of closure, which is nicely boolean, see here: https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/mathcomp/ssreflect/fingraph.v (however, it is not designed for extraction, but for small-step computation in Coq).

Indeed, if you don't want a symmetric closure then it should be directed graphs.

@MevenLennon-Bertrand Yeah, I've already tried the one with mathcomp. connect makes it child's play. But it is not computation-oriented. I was looking for one that can be extracted.

I was foolish enough to make a very futile attempt to replicate connect, but it seems to use so much of mathcomp machinery that's not extraction-friendly.

If I understand what you are requiring correctly (as "won't have any Prop component and would be computation-friendly" is a bit vague), what you are asking for is impossible.
To state it precisely, you assume a type A and decidable relation R : A -> A -> bool (the fact that it targets bool is the decidability part). And you would like to define some Rclose : A -> A -> bool representing its reflexive-transitive closure. However, not all decidable relations have a decidable reflexive-transitive closure.
For instance, take A to be a type of Turing machine states, and R to encode transitions. It is decidable, given two states, whether one can go from one state to another. However, the reflexive transitive closure of R encodes full runs. In particular, if halts : A represents a finished run, Rclos R A halts holds iff A is the starting state of a halting computation. And the halting problem being undecidable says you cannot have such a function…

Would it be possible if I can say that A is a finite type? I edited the question to include some more detail. Would closure be possible then?

By 'no Prop component', I meant extractable.
